# generate sequence (and starting over in case of a recurrence) and add new column with highest number per sequence, within group, in R

Tags: r, sequence, sqldf

I am looking for a way to generate a sequence for a column with names of cities grouped by an ID. What is crucial is that when a name of a city is repeated (within the group) a new sequence has to start. A new sequence should also start in case of a new ID.

EDIT:

The question how to create the above mentioned sequence has been solved. To help select the row with the highest sequence number later on, I am looking for a way to add a new column to the data frame that shows for each record, per sequence, per ID the highest number of each sequence.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve, based on a simplified version of my data frame:

```
ID  City    Sequence    Highest_number
1   Nijmegen    1    2
1   Nijmegen    2    2
1   Arnhem      1    2
1   Arnhem      2    2
1   Nijmegen    1    1
1   Arnhem      1    3
1   Arnhem      2    3
1   Arnhem      3    3
1   Nijmegen    1    1
2   Nijmegen    1    1
2   Utrecht     1    1
2   Amsterdam   1    2
2   Amsterdam   2    2
2   Utrecht     1    4
2   Utrecht     2    4
2   Utrecht     3    4
2   Utrecht     4    4 

mydf <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
        City = c("Nijmegen", "Nijmegen", "Arnhem", "Arnhem", "Nijmegen", 
        "Arnhem", "Arnhem","Arnhem", "Nijmegen", "Nijmegen", "Utrecht", 
       "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Utrecht", "Utrecht", "Utrecht", "Utrecht"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Construct a 'run-length encoding' and use that to generate the sequences

```
rle <- rle(as.character(mydf$City))
mydf$Sequence <- unlist(lapply(rle$length, seq_len))
```

For the updated question, where two columns form the key, paste the columns together with a unique symbol and compute with that

```
rle <- rle(paste(mydf$ID, mydf$City, sep = "\r"))
mydf$Sequence <- unlist(lapply(rle$length, seq_len))
```

This will be 'fast', especially compared to a for loop.

Comment: Quick thanks for drawing attention to `rle()`! Very handy function I did not know about until now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, this solution does not cover the issue that the sequence also has to start over in case of a new ID (group by). I have edited my example so that ID 1 and 2 share a sequence of one city ("Nijmegen").

Comment: @Thijs Instead of creating an rle of `myddf$City`, create it from `paste(mydf$ID, mydf$City, sep="\r")`; this is the approach used in `duplicated.data.frame()`, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

A good old for loop does the trick

```
mydf$Sequence <- NA

for(i in seq_len(nrow(mydf))) {
  if (i == 1 || (mydf$City[i] != mydf$City[i-1]) || (mydf$ID[i] != mydf$ID[i-1]))
    mydf$Sequence[i] <- 1
  else
    mydf$Sequence[i] <- mydf$Sequence[i-1] + 1

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, this solution does not cover the issue that the sequence also has to start over in case of a new ID (group by). I have edited my example so that ID 1 and 2 share a sequence of one city ("Nijmegen").

Comment: See my edit... just add another condition for resetting to 1, if I understand correctly

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it seems to work perfectly with the original data frame. I have edited my post and asked a new question (based on the question that has been solved). I have tried to solve this earlier on by using: mydf_2 <- mydf %>% group_by(ID, City) %>% mutate(Count_2 = tail(n()))  but that is not giving the result I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I'd personnaly go with `sqldf`, if you know SQL you should be able to do that without too much difficulty, using `create table max_values as select ID, city, max(value) from mydf group by id, City;`. Then merge to your existing data.

Comment: Thanks, I could not get create table to work (because of an error) but I managed to do this:  <pre> mydf_2<-sqldf("select ID, City, max(Sequence), from mydf, group by ID, City")  < code> but this code does not take into account that for each sequence of cities, the highest number should be placed in a column because for each id only one unique city is placed in the data frame.

Comment: I see. I would say that this falls in the "ask a new question" area (we don't want questions to become too complex), so I would encourage you to accept whichever response is best for you and take it from there in a new post.