# for-loop through ID-List & counting Values

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, transform

I hope someone can help me with my problem, I know using two for-loops is not very efficient but that was my first solution. I have a data frame (AllPat) with eye-patients (patient-id,  date and visit ->'o'perations or 'c'heckups)

```
#Pat    Date        Visit    
#1,l    2015-03-30    c        
#1,l    2015-06-03    o        
#1,l    2015-07-01    o        
#1,l    2015-07-20    c    
#1,l    2016-03-16    o        
#1,l    2016-04-13    o        
#1,l    2016-05-09    c           
#2,l    2014-12-23    c 
#2,l    2015-01-21    o        
#2,l    2015-03-16    c    
#2,l    2015-11-23    o
```

And I want to count the operation-blocks for each patient-id (before and after a checkup)

```
#Pat    Date        Visit    Block
#1,l    2015-03-30    c        
#1,l    2015-06-03    o        1
#1,l    2015-07-01    o        2
#1,l    2015-07-20    c    
#1,l    2016-03-16    o        1
#1,l    2016-04-13    o        2
#1,l    2016-05-09    c           
#2,l    2014-12-23    c 
#2,l    2015-01-21    o        1
#2,l    2015-03-16    c    
#2,l    2015-11-23    o        1
```

and that's the current code:

```
for(i in unique(AllPat$Pat)){
op <- 0
for(j in AllPat$Pat){
  if(i == j) {
    if(AllPat$Visit[AllPat$Pat == j] == "o") {
      AllPat$Block[AllPat$Pat == j] <- op
      op <- op+1
    }
    else op<-0
  }
}
}
```

my problem is, that the values in $Block only get visible if I sort them by hand in the view of the data frame, maybe someone has a better solution and can help me

---

***UPDATE:***
my current data frame with the suggested function rleid:

```
Patient Date    Visit   DiffDate    Block
3,r 16.02.2016  m       0
3,r 16.02.2016  m   0   0
3,r 16.02.2016  m   0   0
3,r 16.02.2016  m   0   0
3,r 20.04.2016  o   64  1
3,r 18.05.2016  o   28  1 <<- should be 2
3,r 15.06.2016  o   28  1 <<- should be 3
3,r 04.07.2016  m   19  0
3,r 27.07.2016  o   23  1
3,r 24.08.2016  o   28  2
3,r 18.10.2016  o   55  3
```

maybe I should change my difftime function?
The current code for counting the blocks is:

```
n <- nrow(AllPat)
AllPat<- transform(AllPat, Block = ave(1:n, rleid(Patient, Visit, (DiffDate<= 60)), FUN = seq_along) * (Visit== "o"))
```

and the difference between the dates:

```
setDT(AllPat)[, DiffDate:= difftime(AllPat$Date, shift(AllPat$Date), units = "days"), by = c("Patient")]
```

***UPDATE***

```
4,l 2015-05-18  m   NA  0
4,l 2015-10-20  o   155 1 
4,l 2016-05-31  o   224 2 <<-1
4,l 2016-07-26  o   56  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rleid` in the data.table package can help here.  We have used 0 for the checkup blocks.

```
library(data.table)
AllPatDT <- data.table(AllPat)
AllPatDT[, Block := ave(.I, rleid(X.Pat, Visit), FUN = seq_along) * (Visit == "o")]
```

giving:

```
> AllPatDT
    X.Pat       Date Visit Block
 1:  #1,l 2015-03-30     c     0
 2:  #1,l 2015-06-03     o     1
 3:  #1,l 2015-07-01     o     2
 4:  #1,l 2015-07-20     c     0
 5:  #1,l 2016-03-16     o     1
 6:  #1,l 2016-04-13     o     2
 7:  #1,l 2016-05-09     c     0
 8:  #2,l 2014-12-23     c     0
 9:  #2,l 2015-01-21     o     1
10:  #2,l 2015-03-16     c     0
11:  #2,l 2015-11-23     o     1
```

If you prefer a straight data.frame then using only `rleid` from the data.table package we have:

```
library(data.table)

n <- nrow(AllPat)
transform(AllPat, Block = ave(1:n, rleid(X.Pat, Visit), FUN = seq_along) * (Visit == "o"))
```

### Note

We have used the following as `AllPat`:

```
Lines <- "#Pat    Date        Visit    
#1,l    2015-03-30    c        
#1,l    2015-06-03    o        
#1,l    2015-07-01    o        
#1,l    2015-07-20    c    
#1,l    2016-03-16    o        
#1,l    2016-04-13    o        
#1,l    2016-05-09    c           
#2,l    2014-12-23    c 
#2,l    2015-01-21    o        
#2,l    2015-03-16    c    
#2,l    2015-11-23    o"
AllPat <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, comment.char = "", as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: There we go. Added an upvote to your answer and the proper order is restored. I'm perpetually embarrassed that my rep is higher than yours.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick solution, I didn't explain that I only want to count operations to a Block if there is  a difference between 60days ($Days), otherwise the counter starts again. Therefore I already write a new column with the days-difference between two dates (from 2 lines), I didn't explain it in my first question because I believed I could later extend the for-loop with this extra condition, which was obviously not the right way from the beginning

Comment: Add a column `d` which gives the difference in days since the last row and then use `rleid(X.Pat, Visit, cumsum(d <= 60))` or maybe you want > instead of <= depending on if you mean a difference of at most or at least.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thank you, that's my data frame now, I have a new column $Tage with the difference between two date-lines, and used rleid -> rleid(X.Pat, Visit, (Tage <= 60)), because the block-counter should start again, if more than 2 months have passed after one operation, but it starts to count again even if the next op is not after 60Days


--(Date; Visit; Days; Block)--(2016-16-02; "m"; 0; 0)--(2016-20-04; "o"; 64; 1)--(2016-05-18; "o"; 28; 1)  <----- should be 2

Comment: If it's (more than* then you need to add `cumsum(d > 60)` as the third arg to rleid so that a new group is generated each time the `d > 60` condition is met.  Of course it is hard to tell since the data you posted has no examples of runs of `o` values with `d > 60`.

Comment: ok maybe my english is not good enough to explain what my problem is or I just dont get it what you are trying to explain to me
I edit my question with more lines from my current data frame

Comment: There are still no examples of successive dates of o rows that are more than 60 days apart.

Comment: There is less than 60 days between the last 2 rows of the update so the last value of Block should be 2, not 1, in your example and with that correction my suggestion in the comments does work.  `AllPatDT[, Block := ave(.I, 
                        rleid(X.Pat, Visit, cumsum(c(0, diff(as.Date(Date))) >= 60)), 
                        FUN = seq_along) * (Visit == "o")]`

Comment: Thank you, now I get the right Block number, my previous diff-function is now useless, but that's ok for me ;) Can I change your function to label always the last number of a Block or maybe an extra column with the block-size, because  the last date of a block-set is important for me. Or should I open a second question?

Comment: Replace `seq_along` with `function(x) c(0 * x, 1)[-1]` or `length`

Comment: perfect, thank you very much, a lot better than a for-loop-solution

Answer (score 0):

I did a search "[r] sequence within groups" and found an answer that I was able to adapt with a trick I have (in all honesty probably learned from G.Grothendieck) for making groups. This is a link to an answer from Martin Morgan (a certified R guru)

[generate sequence (and starting over in case of a recurrence) and add new column with highest number per sequence, within group, in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298647/generate-sequence-and-starting-over-in-case-of-a-recurrence-and-add-new-column)

I added that to my trick that forms groups at points where a condition occurs:

```
> dat$seq <- cumsum(dat$Visit=="c")
> dat
   Pat       Date Visit seq
1  1,l 2015-03-30     c   1
2  1,l 2015-06-03     o   1
3  1,l 2015-07-01     o   1
4  1,l 2015-07-20     c   2
5  1,l 2016-03-16     o   2
6  1,l 2016-04-13     o   2
7  1,l 2016-05-09     c   3
8  2,l 2014-12-23     c   4
9  2,l 2015-01-21     o   4
10 2,l 2015-03-16     c   5
11 2,l 2015-11-23     o   5
> rle <- rle(paste(dat$Pat, dat$seq, sep = "\r"))
> dat$Seq <- unlist(lapply(rle$length, seq_len))
> dat
   Pat       Date Visit seq Seq
1  1,l 2015-03-30     c   1   1
2  1,l 2015-06-03     o   1   2
3  1,l 2015-07-01     o   1   3
4  1,l 2015-07-20     c   2   1
5  1,l 2016-03-16     o   2   2
6  1,l 2016-04-13     o   2   3
7  1,l 2016-05-09     c   3   1
8  2,l 2014-12-23     c   4   1
9  2,l 2015-01-21     o   4   2
10 2,l 2015-03-16     c   5   1
11 2,l 2015-11-23     o   5   2
> rle <- rle(paste(dat$Pat, dat$seq, sep = "\r"))
> dat$Seq <- dat$Seq -1
> dat$Seq[dat$Seq==0] <- " "
> dat
   Pat       Date Visit seq Seq
1  1,l 2015-03-30     c   1    
2  1,l 2015-06-03     o   1   1
3  1,l 2015-07-01     o   1   2
4  1,l 2015-07-20     c   2    
5  1,l 2016-03-16     o   2   1
6  1,l 2016-04-13     o   2   2
7  1,l 2016-05-09     c   3    
8  2,l 2014-12-23     c   4    
9  2,l 2015-01-21     o   4   1
10 2,l 2015-03-16     c   5    
11 2,l 2015-11-23     o   5   1
```